# appendChild not working properly, shall I find an alternative?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm working on a Drupal website that saves customers data on a PostgreSQL database, using netbeans and glassfish to deploy it. On the webpage there is a JavaScript that saves the data and uses `appendChild`, but it's not working properly. It saves the data only sometimes. The Chrome web console says the function is `undefined`, indicating that line.

Here it is the code:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = direccion_servidor + "setMisDatos?callback=respuestaGuardarMisDatos&param=" + encodeURIComponent(param);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Can anybody help me with this? It's really driving me crazy to not be able to find a solution. What shall I search for? What's an alternative?

Comment: Are you sure the document ready is firing before the code is running?

Comment: Is "respuestaGuardarMisDatos" defined *before* you add the `<script>`?

Comment: actually i didn't write this part of the code, they gave me this to try to fix it, but i don't really know how to make it work out... it's hard for me to understand, i'm not that expert. however, i found this article:

[link][1]


  [1]: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/

which looks like a solution, i'm testing it right now, so if anybody has a better idea ;)

the respuestaGuardarMisDatos function i think is loaded (do you mean, in that js file if it's written before this? in that case the answer'd be yes)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the `<head>` is not yet defined (meaning that it hasn't been closed yet) when your script runs. You should run your script after the `window.onload` event to make sure the DOM is ready for manipulation.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Your code here
};
```

Although this code is certainly not recommended for many reasons. I would recommend using jQuery to save you a headache.

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: actually i didn't write this part of the code, they gave me this to try to fix it, but i don't really know how to make it work out... it's hard for me to understand, i'm not that expert. however, i found this article

Comment: actually i didn't write this part of the code, they gave me this to try to fix it, but i don't really know how to make it work out... it's hard for me to understand, i'm not that expert. however, i found this article:

[link][1]


  [1]: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/

which looks like a solution, i'm testing it right now, so if anybody has a better idea ;)

the respuestaGuardarMisDatos function i think is loaded (do you mean, in that js file if it's written before this? in that case the answer'd be yes)

Comment: it's still not working properly, i don't understand why it looks like that for some users it works good, and for other ones works 80% of the time... any idea?